# When does a monic arrow in $\mathcal{C}^\rightarrow$ implies the corresponding arrows are monic in $\mathcal{C}$?

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category, and let $(\varphi, \psi)$ be an arrow in the arrow category $\mathcal{C}^\rightarrow$, where $\varphi : a \rightarrow a'$, $\psi : b \rightarrow b'$, and there exist $f : a \rightarrow b$, $g : a' \rightarrow b'$ such that the corresponding square commutes (that is, $\psi \circ f = g \circ \varphi$). Let's also assume $(\varphi, \psi)$ is monic in $\mathcal{C}^\rightarrow$. What does it tell us about $\varphi, \psi$ in $\mathcal{C}$?

First, I managed to prove the following: if $\xi_1, \xi_2 : c \rightarrow a, \chi_1, \chi_2 : d \rightarrow b$ are such that $(\xi_1, \chi_1)$ and $(\xi_2, \chi_2)$ are arrows in $\mathcal{C}^\rightarrow$ and such that $\varphi \circ \xi_1 = \varphi \circ \xi_2$ and $\psi \circ \chi_1 = \psi \circ \chi_2$, then $\xi_1 = \xi_2$ and $\chi_1 = \chi_2$:

[image]

That is, $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are monomorphisms *if* we restrict our arrows in $\mathcal{C}$ to the ones that make it into arrows in the arrow category.

Can we do better?

Let's take arbitrary $\xi_1, \xi_2 : c \rightarrow a$, also take $c$ as $d$ (and hence $h = \text{id}_c$), and take $\chi_1 = f \circ \xi_1, \chi_2 = f \circ \xi_2$. Then it follows that, in particular, $\varphi \circ \xi_1 = \varphi \circ \xi_2 \Rightarrow \xi_1 = \xi_2$, hence $\varphi$ is monic in $\mathcal{C}$.

Can we do a similar trick to prove $\psi$ is monic?

The best I could come up with is the following. Assume $\mathcal{C}$ has initial objects, take $c = 0$ and arbitrary $\chi_1, \chi_2 : d \rightarrow b$:

[image]

Then the leftmost square commutes, and by a similar argument we see $\psi$ is monic.

Does it make sense? If so, can I do the $\psi$ part without assuming initial objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $C$ has an initial object $0$. Then, the codomain functor $C^{\rightarrow} \to C$ has a left adjoint sending each object $X$ of $C$ to the unique arrow $0 \to X$, and so it preserves monomorphisms.

Your proof that the codomain functor preserves monomorphisms is just a special case of the general proof of the fact that right adjoint functors preserve monomorphisms.

Also, regardless of the existence of an initial object in $C$, the domain functor $C^{\rightarrow} \to C$ always has a left adjoint sending each object of $C$ to its identity arrow. And again, your proof that the domain functor preserves monomorphisms is just a special case of the general proof for right adjoint functors.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that's indeed the case! Unfortunately I'm quite early in my CT learning (just going through the first chapters of Goldblatt's "Topoi"), so I'm not supposed to know what a functor is, and I was curious how much could I achieve without that knowledge.